# How to make bash wrapper script to execute java jar that takes stdin and outputs to stdout

Tags: java, bash, io-redirection

I've made a java program that takes input from stdin and returns output to stdout, which runs perfectly fine using:

```
cat inputfile | java -jar whatever.jar <args>
```

I want to make a bash wrapper script to put in my `~/bin` so I can just run

```
cat inputfile | whatever
```

, which would perform exactly the same function.

How can I make a wrapper script that just passes stdin unmolested to the jar, while simultaneously receiving stdout back to echo to the CLI?

I think I can achieve it one-way to send the inputfile to the command, but have no idea how to get the output from the command back simultaneously.

Comment: BTW, `cat inputfile | whatever` is what's often called a "useless use of cat"; it's simpler sometimes better to use an input redirect, like `whatever <inputfile`.

Comment: What problem do you have when you try to just put `java -jar whatever.jar` in your script? I'm assuming something went wrong to cause the question. What went wrong when you tried it yourself, without doing anything special to try to pass stdin and stdout through (as, indeed, you _don't need to_ do anything special for that purpose).

Comment: Right now, the question describes what you're trying to do, but it doesn't describe the _specific problem_ you encountered while trying to do it, nor does it provide a [mre] letting others see that problem themselves or test whether it has been successfully resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
#!/bin/bash
exec java -jar whatever.jar "$@"
```

**Discussion:**

Like all Unix shells, Bash has a special variable named `$@`. It contains the argument list of a shell script. I would use it to receive the `<args>` of `whatever.jar`.

This way, Bash never even touches the `stdin` and `stdout` of `whatever.jar`. It simply has `java` call `whatever.jar`, passes `<args>` to it by way of `$@`, and gets out of the way. All reading from `stdin` and writing to `stdout` gets done by `whatever.jar` directly.

Comment: You should double-quote the `$@` (i.e. use `"$@"`) to avoid mangling arguments that contain spaces or other "funny" characters. Also, this would be a good place to use the `exec` command (i.e. `exec java -jar whatever.jar "$@"`), which prevents the shell script from hanging out waiting for the java program to finish -- with `exec`, the shell script effectively exits immediately, and hands off to the `java` program.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Gordon! You're right. I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar whatever.jar <args>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your bash script should only contain the java call.

Then redirect the file as input to the script:

```
./script < inputfile
```